# index out of bounds swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimage, indexoutofboundsexception

i can't figure out why my array is out of bounds. i put the feed items into an array "imageArray" and it gives me fatal error heres code

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BlogPost

    let blogPost: BlogPost = blogPosts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = blogPost.postTitle
   // cell.textLabel?.text = blogPost.postImageLink
    if cell.postImage?.image == nil {
  //  let cache = ImageLoadingWithCache()
      //  cache.getImage(self.postImageLink,  imageView: cell.postImage, defaultImage: "IMG_0079")}
   if cell.postImage?.image == nil {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        // retrieve image from url
        let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:self.postImageLink)!)!)
        self.imageArray.append(image!)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { Void in
            // set image in main thread

            cell.postImage?.image =  self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
        })
    }
    } else {
            cell.postImage?.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_0079")
        }

    }

    return cell
}
```

specifically the error is here

```
 cell.postImage?.image =  self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
```

any ideas?

Comment: try using this extension UIImageView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift/27712427#27712427

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because `indexPath` is captured when the closure is created and then by the time the closure is called the `indexPath.row` is stale and out of bounds. Not to mention that you are force-unwrapping a lot in there, what if some of those `Optional` are unset? Test and unwrap them properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TableView number of rows in section must have the same value as your imageArray count. That signify : if you have 10 cells and only 9 images, the 10th cell would look for the 10th image which do not exist.

To be sure that the error does not appear anymore, just add the following *if statement* before setting your cell :

```
if (indexPath.row < self.imageArray.count) { }
```

Or as [ColGraff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887210/colgraff) said

> A guard statement would better indicate what you're doing

```
guard indexPath.row < self.imageArray.count else { return }
```

Before your cell edition.

Those two solutions should avoid you any troubles.

Comment: A `guard` statement would better indicate what you're doing: `guard indexPath.row < self.imageArray.count else { return }`

Comment: Yes, for sure, but both work ! It is up to him to decide if he prefer use it or not ! A lot of different solutions work ^^

Comment: Of course! I added the comment because this is a good place to use `guard`, this situation is one reason it was added to the language.

Comment: i appreciate the help i used the guard statement  before ""cell.postImage?.image =  self.imageArray[indexPath.row]" is that correct? Also this did get rid of my problem I'm just double checking